# Meteor subscription ready

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'am building a react/meteor app. I'm having a problem with subscriptions. There's a  component that is showed when the subscriotion.ready() is false. When it's turned to true the  component is replaced by a table with data, but it takes a few seconds between the ready and the data from find().fetch(), showing another component  for a while.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `react-meteor-data` you can get the `subscription` status in `ready` property. Then you can send this property to the presentation component and update it accordingly.

Sample code snippet from the package's documentation:

```
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export default PresenterContainer = createContainer(props => {
  // Do all your reactive data access in this method.
  // Note that this subscription will get cleaned up when your component is unmounted
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('publication_name');

  return {
    isReady: ! handle.ready(),
    list: CollectionName.find().fetch(),
  };
}, PresenterComponent);
```

Explanation: 
The first argument to `createContainer` is a reactive function that will get re-run whenever its reactive inputs change.

The `PresenterComponent` component will receive {isReady, list} as props. So, you can render your component according to the status of `isReady`

**Addition**:
Write your `render` method of the  presenter component like this:

```
render(){
    if(!this.isReady) return <LoadingComponent/>
    else if(this.props.list.length() != 0) return <TableComponent/>
    else return <NoDataFoundComponent/>
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks.. I was doing almost this, just I had a Meteor.autorun where the subscription was in, I remove it but the delay between the ready and the data from find still there. It's about 1 second, just enough to show the component that says "no records found".

Comment: thanks, i just fixed it changing the parameter watched by the "no records found" component, now it's based on the ready and the counts.get()==0. now It's a time between the loading component remove and the data but its much better without the "no records found" component.

Comment: I've updated my answer, if it helps don't forget to upvote or accept! :)